# DSI display with core-image-x11 build of 4.1.3 Langdale

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, x11, lcd, xrandr

I posted to the Raspberry Pi forum about this the link is below. I am using a fresh build of Yocto Langdale 4.1.3 with the core-image-x11 image.

[Raspberry Pi forum DSI display issue with Yocto](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=350438)

Basically the problem is that I have a 7" DSI display that is supposed to work without any special drivers with just the overlays.

My DSI display shows the text at bootup and the raspberry pi logo/loading screen but thats it.

If I connect an HDMI display everything works fine.

If I run "xrandr -q" it shows that the DSI display is connected and I can use the touchscreen of the DSI display to move the cursor on the hdmi screen.

How do I configure xinit/xrandr/matchbox-window-manager so that the terminal/x11 UI appears on the DSI display.

I am not sure what I need to do to make the display work.

What I want is for the X11 image to start up and display on the DSI display. I do not need HDMI to also work though if I could duplicate the output of the display over HDMI that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why the displays wouldn't work I was vastly overcomplicating things.

So I was trying to run these displays on a CM4 module on an IO board.

I was using the following overlays to try and get things working. All of the tutorials I saw on Waveshare and other sites said to use these overlays.

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch
```

I switched the overlays over to the following. I tried this on a whim and was quite happy with the result.

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-dsi-7inch
```

The displays now work and boot up to the DSI display perfectly.

Now I just need to remove the the window box manager x button and border around the terminal that opens and should be good to go from there.